# Trace of a diagonalized matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, spectral-theory

Why do I have: $Tr(SDS^{-1})=Tr(D)$?

Comment: $A^k$ and $D$ are similar. Similar matrices always have the same trace.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that for any matrices $A$ and $B$ we have $\def\tr{\mathop{\rm Tr}}\tr(AB) = \tr(BA)$. To see this, one can argue as follows:
\begin{align*}
  \tr(AB) &= \sum_i (AB)_{ii}\\
          &= \sum_i \sum_j A_{ij}B_{ji}\\
          &=\sum_j \sum_i B_{ji}A_{ij}\\
          &= \sum_j (BA)_{jj}\\
          &= \tr(BA)
\end{align*}
Hence $$ \tr(S^{-1}DS) = \tr(DSS^{-1}) = \tr(D). $$

Answer (score 2):

It's the defining property of the trace that it is cyclic; that is

\begin{align*}
 Tr(AB) = Tr(BA)
\end{align*}

so in your case

\begin{align*}
  Tr(SDS^{-1}) = Tr(DSS^{-1}) = Tr(D)
\end{align*}
as $S S^{-1} = I$.

Comment: What definition of trace are you referring to? In my book the trace of a matrix is just the sum of its diagonal entries, and this definition does not involve (but implies) "being cyclic". I am aware that, like the determinant, there are sophisticated ways of characterizing the trace, but one should not confuse characterisation and definition.

Comment: @Marc - What I mean was that if you ask for a linear operator that is cyclic, you get the trace. You've got me though, I can't find a reference for it at the moment.